# Java. Arithmetic operations.tokenized. How?

Tags: java, tokenize

Who can explain or give a good reference for understanding this example:

```
int a=1;
int b=2;
System.out.println(a---b); //correct
System.out.println(a- -b); //correct
System.out.println(a--b); //wrong
```

thanks.

Comment: It's not just the tokenization. You need to understand the parsing as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `a---b` is not (as you perhaps expected) parsed as `a-(-(-b))` but rather as `(a--) - b`.

This example illustrates it:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
System.out.println(a---b);  // prints 0
System.out.println(a);      // prints -1
```

With this behaviour in mind, `a--b` is parsed as `(a--)b` which is obviously an error.

When you put a space between the minuses, `a- -b` it's no longer parsed as the `--` operator, but as a binary and unary minus: `a - (-b)`.

Note that you can write `a- - -b` which is interpreted as `a-(-(-b))`.

So *why* is it interpreted like this? Well @EJP gave an excellent comment on another answer. In the [JLS, section 3.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.2) you can read the following:

> *The longest possible translation is used at each step, even if the result does not ultimately make a correct program while another lexical translation would. Thus the input characters `a--b` are tokenized (§3.5) as `a`, `--`, `b`, which is not part of any grammatically correct program, even though the tokenization `a`, `-`, `-`, `b` could be part of a grammatically correct program.*

Answer (score 0):

[The Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html).

Comment: That's the correct reference. Any programmer should be able to find his way around a language spec.

Comment: @EJP, can you tell me how to find the answer to the OPs question in the JLS? I tried and failed. Specifically, I'm looking for the reason why `a---b` is interpreted as `a-- -b` and not as `a - - -b` or `a - --b`.

Comment: @Will, ok. That link is better. But please tell me why `a---b` is parsed as `Identifier (a), PostfixOp (--), PrefixOp (-), Identifier (b)` and not as `Identifier (a), InfixOp (-), PrefixOp (--), Identifier (b)`. Both looks fine to me according to the grammar on that page.

Comment: Because as it says in #3.2, the longest possible translation is used at every step.

Comment: @EJP, now that would have made an excellent answer. It even brings up the `--` thing as an example.

Comment: And it's all in  the JLS right where Will said in the first place. I still don't know why you weren't able to find it for yourself, nor why the downvote on this perfectly correct answer.

Comment: no, but the language specification is the *authoritative* source for describing the language

Answer (score 0):

`-` and `--` are unary operators. Therefore can't be used with two operands. That's why

```
System.out.println(a--b);
```

is wrong. `--` is applied to `a`, so the new value of `a` is `0`. If you add one more `-`, then the value of `a` decremented by `1` will be subtracted by the value of `b` yielding `-2`